# C++ reading 16bit Wav file

Tags: c++, audio, wav

I'm having trouble reading in a 16bit .wav file. I have read in the header information, however, the conversion does not seem to work.

For example, in Matlab if I read in wave file I get the following type of data:

```
 -0.0064, -0.0047,  -0.0051, -0.0036, -0.0046, -0.0059,  -0.0051
```

However, in my C++ program the following is returned:

```
0.960938, -0.00390625, -0.949219, -0.00390625, -0.996094, -0.00390625
```

I need the data to be represented the same way. Now, for `8 bit` .wav files I did the following:

```
uint8_t c;

for(unsigned i=0; (i < size); i++)
{
    c = (unsigned)(unsigned char)(data[i]);
    double t = (c-128)/128.0;
    rawSignal.push_back(t);
}
```

This worked, however, when I did this for 16bit:

```
uint16_t c;

for(unsigned i=0; (i < size); i++)
{
   c = (signed)(signed char)(data[i]);
   double t = (c-256)/256.0;
   rawSignal.push_back(t);
}
```

Does not work and shows the output (above).

I'm following the standards found [Here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html)

Where `data` is a `char` array and `rawSignal` is a `std::vector<double>` I'm probably just handing the conversion wrong but cannot seem to find out where. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is what is now displaying (In a graph):

[image]

This is what it should be displaying:

[image]

Comment: Since data is an array of characters then data[i] refers to the i-th character, an 8 bit item, not the i-th 16 bit value.

Comment: @Jay Sorry?? Do I need to re-arrange the data then? I'm confused now.

Comment: If you've specified 'data' is an array of 8 bit values then data[3] retrieves the 3th byte of the array. If you've got 16 bit values in the array then data[3] will not get you the 3rd 16 bit value.

Comment: @Jay But, `data` is just a char array. I don't specify that it is `8bits` or anything.. E.g. `data = new char[padded_size];` so should this therefore be a `16bit char array`?

Comment: @user1326876 - a `char` is an element of defined size.  On most of the processors you encounter this will be 8 bits, though there are exceptions (some TI DSPs for example).

Comment: Your title says this is 16 bit data. 16 bit data will not fit into a char. You need to treat the data as an array of signed 16-bit elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

- 8 bit wavs are unsigned, but 16 bit wavs are signed. Therefore, the subtraction step given in the answers by Carl and Jay are unnecessary. I presume they just copied from your code, but they are wrong.
- 16 bit waves have a range from -32,768 to 32,767, not from -256 to 255, making the multiplication you are using incorrect anyway.
- 16-bit wavs are 2 bytes, thus you must read two bytes to make one sample, not one. You appear to be reading one character at a time. When you read the bytes, you may have to swap them if your native endianness is not little-endian.

Assuming a **little-endian** architecture, your code would look more like this (very close to Carl's answer):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
{
    int c = (data[i + 1] << 8) | data[i];
    double t = c/32768.0;
    rawSignal.push_back(t);
}
```

for a **big-endian** architecture:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
{
    int c = (data[i] << 8) | data[i+1];
    double t = c/32768.0;
    rawSignal.push_back(t);
}
```

That code is untested, so please LMK if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked out your signal processing / audio processing work and it's impressive :) I'll attempt this once I get a chance. I have a big problem that.. It's not reading the correct "size" for 16bit audio files, but, it is for 8bit files.. I'll check later though thank you :)

Comment: No, this does not work. Tried for both little-endian and big-endian

Comment: "It's not reading the correct "size" for 16bit audio files, but, it is for 8bit files" so you are not reading the header correctly. Perhaps you are starting to read the data at the wrong byte.

Comment: Also, what architecture are you running on? Perhaps you should include your code for reading the header as well.

Comment: Finally works :) I needed sleep aha! Cheers. Also, is there a way to check if the person has little-endian or big-endian architecture?

Comment: Most compilers produce macros for endianness.

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for your help :) I'll read into this!!

Comment: This did not work.. Seems so long ago now! I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345689/c-reading-in-16bit-wav-files there is just a small difference in the results and I haven't a clue why this is happening. If you get time, would you please take a look.. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's biased. If you need to know how it works, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

(First of all about little-endian/big-endian-ness. WAV is just a container format, the data encoded in it can be in countless format. Most of the codecs are lossless (MPEG Layer-3 aka MP3, yes, the stream can be "packaged" into a WAV, various CCITT and other codecs). You assume that you deal with some kind of PCM format, where you see the actual wave in RAW format, no lossless transformation was done on it. The endianness depends on the codec, which produced the stream.
[Is the endianness of format params guaranteed in RIFF WAV files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111539/is-the-endianness-of-format-params-guaranteed-in-riff-wav-files))

It's also a question if the one PCM sample is in linear scale sampled integer or there some scaling, log scale or other transformation behind it. Regular PCM wav files I encountered were simple linear scale samples, but I'm not working in the audio recording or producing industry.

So a path to your solution:

1. Make sure that you are dealing with regular 16 bit PCM encoded RIFF WAV file.
2. While reading the stream, always read two bytes (char) at a time and convert the two chars into a 16 bit short. People showed this before me.
3. The wave form you show clearly suggest that you either not estimated the **frequency** well (or you just have one **mono channel** instead of a **stereo**). Because the sampling rate (44.1kHz, 22KHz, 11KHz, 8kHz, etc) is just as important as the resolution (8 bit, 16 bit, 24 bit, etc). Maybe in the first case you had a stereo data. You can read it in as mono, you may not notice it. In the second case if you have mono data, then you'll run out of samples half way into reading the data. That's what it seems to happen according to your graphs. Talking about the other cause: the lower sampling resolutions (and 16 bit is also lower) often paired with lower sampling rates. So if your input data is the recording time, and you think you have a 22kHz data, but it's actually just 11kHz, then again you'll run out half way through from the actual samples and read in memory garbage. So either one of these.

Make sure that you interpret and treat your loop iterator variable and the size well. It seems that size tells how many bytes you have. You'll have exactly half as much short integer samples. Notice, that Bjorn's solution correctly increments i by 2 because of that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Could this be the problem why I am not returning the correct size for a 16bit .wav file when the correct size for an 8bit .wav file returns the correct size? Should I therefore be `size / 2`?

Comment: The stream size in the header is probably correct, and if it says that the audio stream contained in the wav file is `x`, then you should have `x` bytes there (otherwise your file is truncated). What I'm saying is that with 16 bit PCM samples the size is `x`, but you have `x / 2` number of samples in that data. If your loop says `i += 2`, then you are OK in this respect. But you see that your graph start to be weird exactly at half time. So something gone wrong. We need more info to tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My working code is

```
int8_t* buffer = new int8_t[size];
/*
  HERE buffer IS FILLED
*/
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
{
    int16_t c = ((unsigned char)buffer[i + 1] << 8) | (unsigned char)buffer[i];
    double t = c/32768.0;
    rawSignal.push_back(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 16-bit quantity gives you a range from -32,768 to 32,767, not from -256 to 255 (that's just 9 bits). Use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
{
    c = (data[i + 1] << 8) + data[i]; // WAV files are little-endian
    double t = (c - 32768)/32768.0;
    rawSignal.push_back(t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This gives me: `0.992493
0.992584
0.992218
0.983398
0.994781` Which is not right compared to the result in MatLab?

Comment: What do you mean by `logs` sorry? Could you give me an example

Comment: I mean print out some data and see if you're reading out the bytes that are in the file correclty.

Comment: Yeah, I have done. All the header information is correct. I'm printing out `data[i]` seems to be ok as well. mhm this is strange.

Comment: Not sure about the appropriateness of the subtraction, as .wav files are typically signed.  Also, it matters if data is a signed or unsigned 8 bit type, as unwanted sign extension of the less significant byte can cause problems.

Comment: the subtraction is incorrect for 16-bit files. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want something more like this:

```
uint16_t c;
for(unsigned i=0; (i < size); i++)
{
   // get a 16 bit pointer to the array
   uint16_t* p = (uint16_t*)data;
   // get the i-th element
   c = *( p + i );
   // convert to signed? I'm guessing this is what you want
   int16_t cs = (int16_t)c;
   double t = (cs-256)/256.0;
   rawSignal.push_back(t);
}
```

Your code converts the 8 bit value to a signed value then writes it into an unsigned variable. You should look at that and see if it's what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It kind of works, however, take a look at my original post i've uploaded 2 graphs. I don't understand where the "block" is coming from.. But, it's close to what I want :) Hope you can help me

Comment: This is wrong on at least two counts: no need to subtract 256 and 256 is the wrong scaling factor for 16 bit. Also, it assumes a little endian architecture. The pointer arithmetic is hard to follow... not sure it's right.