# C++ - Reading in 16bit .wav files

Tags: python, c++, audio

I'm trying to read in a .wav file, which I thought was giving me the correct result, however, when I plot the same audio file in Matlab or Python, the results are different.

This is the result that I get:

[image]

This is the result that Python (plotted with matplotlib) gives:

[image]

The results do not seem that different, but, when it comes to analysis, this is messing up my results.

Here is the code that converts:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
{
    int c = (data[i + 1] << 8) | data[i];
    double t = c/32768.0;
                //cout << t << endl;
    rawSignal.push_back(t);
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Since, this conversion seems fine and does produce such a similar results.

Thanks

EDIT:

Code to read the header / data:

```
voidreadHeader(ifstream& file) {



 s_riff_hdr riff_hdr;
    s_chunk_hdr chunk_hdr;

    long padded_size; // Size of extra bits

    vector<uint8_t> fmt_data; // Vector to store the FMT data.

    s_wavefmt *fmt = NULL;

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&riff_hdr), sizeof(riff_hdr));
    if (!file) return false;

    if (memcmp(riff_hdr.id, "RIFF", 4) != 0) return false;

    //cout << "size=" << riff_hdr.size << endl;
    //cout << "type=" << string(riff_hdr.type, 4) << endl;

    if (memcmp(riff_hdr.type, "WAVE", 4) != 0) return false;
    {
         do
         {
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&chunk_hdr), sizeof(chunk_hdr));
            if (!file) return false;
            padded_size = ((chunk_hdr.size + 1) & ~1);

            if (memcmp(chunk_hdr.id, "fmt ", 4) == 0) 
            {
                if (chunk_hdr.size < sizeof(s_wavefmt)) return false;

                fmt_data.resize(padded_size);
                file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&fmt_data[0]), padded_size);
                if (!file) return false;

                fmt = reinterpret_cast<s_wavefmt*>(&fmt_data[0]);

                sample_rate2 = fmt->sample_rate;

                if (fmt->format_tag == 1) // PCM
                {
                    if (chunk_hdr.size < sizeof(s_pcmwavefmt)) return false;

                    s_pcmwavefmt *pcm_fmt = reinterpret_cast<s_pcmwavefmt*>(fmt);


                    bits_per_sample = pcm_fmt->bits_per_sample;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (chunk_hdr.size < sizeof(s_wavefmtex)) return false;

                    s_wavefmtex *fmt_ex = reinterpret_cast<s_wavefmtex*>(fmt);


                    if (fmt_ex->extra_size != 0)
                    {
                        if (chunk_hdr.size < (sizeof(s_wavefmtex) + fmt_ex->extra_size)) return false;

                        uint8_t *extra_data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(fmt_ex + 1);
                        // use extra_data, up to extra_size bytes, as needed...
                    }

                }
                //cout << "extra_size=" << fmt_ex->extra_size << endl;
            }

            else if (memcmp(chunk_hdr.id, "data", 4) == 0)
            {
                // process chunk data, according to fmt, as needed...
                size = padded_size;

                if(bits_per_sample == 16)
                {
                    //size = padded_size / 2;
                }

                data = new unsigned char[size];

                file.read(data,     size);

                file.ignore(padded_size);
                if (!file) return false;
            }
            {
                // process other chunks as needed...

                file.ignore(padded_size);
                if (!file) return false;
            }

        }while (!file.eof());
         return true;
     }

 }
```

This is where the "conversion to double" happens :

```
if(bits_per_sample == 8)
        {
            uint8_t c;  
            //cout << size;
            for(unsigned i=0; (i < size); i++)
            {
                c = (unsigned)(unsigned char)(data[i]);
                double t = (c-128)/128.0;
                rawSignal.push_back(t);
            }
        }
        else if(bits_per_sample == 16)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
            {
                int c;
                c = (unsigned) (unsigned char) (data[i + 2] << 8) | data[i];
                double t = c/32768.0;
                rawSignal.push_back(t);
        }
```

Note how "8bit" files work correctly?

Comment: The code that converts _what_? What are `size` and `data` there? What is the corresponding Python code that you're trying to duplicate?

Comment: And what is the "raw" format in that `rawSignal`? Usually float audio either ranges from -1 to 1 or 0 to 1, but it looks like you're going to range from 0 to 2 (because you take an int from 0-65535, assuming `data` is an `unsigned char *`, and then divide it by 32768.0).

Comment: @abarnert I would like to convert the raw data, into a "double" hence the `/32768.0`

Comment: Yes, but presumably not just "a double", but a double in some standard format. Again, the `/32768.0` will give you a double from 0.0-2.0, which I doubt is what you want. Unless `data` is an array of _signed_ characters, in which case you've got a different problem.

Comment: @abarnert data is just a normal char `char* data;` but, the result ranges above 2.0 which is where I think the problem is. What would be the fault here? I'm looking through my code and cannot see it anywhere

Comment: OK, I think I know the problem. See my answer.

Comment: On most platforms, `char` is signed. And meanwhile, the reason your 8-bit values work is that the problem is an attempt to use unsigned-specific byte-swapping code on signed numbers, which you don't do on 8-bit values, so of course it doesn't affect them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your problem may be that `data` is an array of *signed* `char` values. So, when you do this:

```
int c = (data[i + 1] << 8) | data[i];
```

… it's not actually doing what you wanted. Let's look at some simple examples.

If `data[i+1] == 64` and `data[i] == 64`, that's going to be 0x4000 | 0x40, or 0x4040, all good.

If `data[i+1] == -64` and `data[i] == -64`, that's going to be 0xffffc000 | 0xffffffc0, or 0xffffffc0, which is obviously wrong.

If you were using `unsigned char` values, this would work, because instead of -64 those numbers would be 192, and you'd end up with 0xc000 | 0xc0 or 0xc0c0, just as you want. (But then your `/32768.0` would give you numbers in the range 0.0 to 2.0, when you presumably want -1.0 to 1.0.)

Suggesting a "fix" is difficult without knowing what exactly you're trying to do. Obviously you want to convert some kind of 16-bit little-endian integer format into some kind of floating-point format, but a lot rests on the exact details of those formats, and you haven't provided any such details. The default .wav format is 16-bit unsigned little-endian integers, so just using `unsigned char *` would fix that part of the equation. But I don't know of any audio format that uses 64-bit floating point numbers from 0.0 to 2.0, and I don't know what audio format you're actually aiming for, so I can't say what that `/32768.0` should actually be, just that it's probably wrong.

Comment: As you can see, I have no unsigned or signed chars for the `data` so how can that be the problem?

Comment: @user1326876 you say `data` is `char*`, which on most systems means it's a signed data type. Values will range from -128 to 127 rather than 0 to 255.

Comment: The scale isn't 0.0 to 2.0, it's -1.0 to 1.0. That's OK for processing purposes.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - so where would the problem be? I mean the two graphs look identical with just a few minor differences

Comment: @user1326876 declare `data` as `unsigned char*` or `uint8_t*` and try again.

Comment: @Mark ransom - ok thanks I'll try that and see where it gets me :)

Comment: @user1326876 P.S. I'd say this *has* to be the answer. Look at those waveforms closely and see where they're flat-topped? That's the point where it crosses over from positive to negative.

Comment: @mark ransom - it cannot be that simple to fix, can it? I can't try it yet as I'm not in the lab atm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46073/discussion-between-user1326876-and-mark-ransom)

Comment: The final answer required a mix of signed and unsigned: `int c = ((int)(char)data[i+1])<<8 | ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)data[i]);`

Comment: If you're trying to read little-endian signed shorts, I think it's clearer to use (short *) and then explicitly byte-swap the shorts if necessary than to case the chars back and forth between different types.