# Unsure of normalising double values loaded as 2 bytes each

Tags: c++, double, wav

The code that I'm using for reading .wav file data into an 2D array:

```
        int signal_frame_width = wavHeader.SamplesPerSec / 100; //10ms frame
        int total_number_of_frames = numSamples / signal_frame_width;
        double** loadedSignal = new double *[total_number_of_frames]; //array that contains the whole signal

        int iteration = 0;
        int16_t* buffer = new int16_t[signal_frame_width];
        while ((bytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), signal_frame_width, wavFile)) > 0)
        {
            loadedSignal[iteration] = new double[signal_frame_width];
            for(int i = 0; i < signal_frame_width; i++){
                //value normalisation:
                int16_t c = (buffer[i + 1] << 8) | buffer[i];
                double normalisedValue = c/32768.0;

                loadedSignal[iteration][i] = normalisedValue;
            }
            iteration++;
        }
```

The problem is in this part, I don't exaclty understand how it works:

```
int16_t c = (buffer[i + 1] << 8) | buffer[i];
```

It's example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771375/c-reading-16bit-wav-file). 
I'm working on 16bit .wav files only. As you can see, my buffer is loading (for ex. sampling freq. = 44.1kHz) 441 elements (each is 2byte signed sample). How should I change above code?

Comment: Why do you want to change the code? It is not clear from your question whether you just want to understand what that line does, or if you want to change something.

Comment: Both. I don't understand this line and I don't understand how to change it, that will operate on my loaded 2byte values (the code I mentioned works when fread paramater 'size' = 1 byte, its 'size' = 2 bytes in my example).

Comment: You probably don't need that line at all. int16_t c = buffer[i];

Comment: That piece of code assumes that buffer is an array of bytes. It is interpreting two consecutive bytes as a single 16-bit integer, assuming that the bytes are in little-endian order. Your buffer is not an array of bytes, it is already an array of 16-bit ints. Also you are iterating with step-size 1, where you would need step-size 2 to apply such logic. In your case you don't need that since you have already interpreted the data as 16-bit ints when you read them (although now you have no control over endianess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original example, from which you constructed your code, used an array where each individual element represented a *byte*.  It therefore needs to combine two consecutive bytes into a 16-bit value, which is what this line does:

```
int16_t c = (buffer[i + 1] << 8) | buffer[i];
```

It shifts the byte at index `i+1` (here assumed to be the most significant byte) left by 8 positions, and then ORs the byte at index `i` onto that.  For example, if `buffer[i+1]==0x12` and `buffer[i]==0x34`, then you get

```
buffer[i+1] << 8 == 0x12 << 8 == 0x1200
0x1200 | buffer[i] == 0x1200 | 0x34 == 0x1234
```

(The `|` operator is a bitwise OR.)

Note that you need to be careful whether your WAV file is little-endian or big-endian (but the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771375/c-reading-16bit-wav-file) explains that quite well).

Now, if you store the resulting value in a *signed* 16-bit integer, you get a value between −32768 and +32767.  The point in the actual normalization step (dividing by 32768) is just to bring the value range down to [−1.0, 1.0).

In your case above, you appear to already be reading into a buffer of 16-bit values.  Note that your code will therefore only work if the endianness of your platform matches that of the WAV file you are working with.  But if this assumption is correct, then you don't need the code line which you do not understand.  You can just convert every array element into a double directly:

```
double normalisedValue = buffer[i]/32768.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If `buffer` was an array of bytes, then that piece of code would interpret two consecutive bytes as a single 16-bit integer (assuming little-endian encoding). The `|` operator will perform a bit-wise OR on the bits of the two bytes. Since we wish to interpret the two bytes as a single 2-byte integer, then we must shift the bits of one of them 8 bits (1 byte) to the left. Which one depends on whether they are ordered in little-endian or big-endian order. Little-endian means that the least significant byte comes first, so we shift the second byte 8 bits to the left.

Example:

```
First byte: 0101 1100
Second byte: 1111 0100
```

Now shift second byte:

```
Second "byte": 1111 0100 0000 0000
First "byte":  0000 0000 0101 1100
```

Bitwise OR-operation (if either is 1, then 1. If both are 0, then 0):
16-bit integer: `1111 0100 0101 1100`

In your case however, the bytes in your file have already been interpreted as 16-bit ints using whatever endianness the platform has. So you do not need this step. However, in order to correctly interpret the bytes in the file, one must assume the same byte-order as they were written in. Therefore, one usually adds this step to ensure that the code works independent of the endianness of the platform, instead relying on the expected byte-order of the files (as most file formats will specify what the byte-order should be).